# How to save values with PHP in dynamic memory?

Tags: php, memory

I need to create a simple form which saves it's values in a dynamic memory. So far the code goes like this:

```
                <tr>
                    <td>Code:</td>
                    <td><input type="text" name="code" /></td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td>Name:</td>
                    <td><input type="text" name="name" /></td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td>Inventory number</td>
                    <td><input type="text" name="number" /></td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td>Value</td>
                    <td><input type="text" name="value" /></td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td>Buy value</td>
                    <td><input type="text" name="buy_value" /></td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td></td>
                    <td><input type="submit" name="add" value="Add" /></td>
                </tr>
```

So how can I add it not to a database, but to something like a multidimensional array or something like that, and I must be able to delete a selected record afterwards.

Comment: Which db you are using?, what you have tried?, past some code....

Comment: If you want it only on the current script run then you could use any standard PHP Array. If you want this data to remain there for you for the whole session on multiple requests then you could use `$_SESSION / $_COOKIES`

Comment: If you don't want to store data on database, you must have to use XML for storing data.

Answer (score 0):

You can save it in session data. This, however, will be lost upon session end (say if user closes the browser).

```
session_start();
$_SESSION = array_merge($_SESSION, $_POST);
```

I used `array_merge` so that previous data you might had there won't be lost.

Answer (score 0):

you can submit your form data into a file that displays them in tables, arrays and etc and yet you can delete the selected row or index or etc using jquery(javascript) functions and then what? where is the form data going to go? no sustainable storage? loosing data on page change?

Answer (score 0):

Im not sure exactly what you are going for but if the code that you posted is inside of a form and the forms action is to post data to your php script then

```
  extract($_POST);
```

will store the values of each input field into a php scalar of the same name as the input field's name. From there you can easily go about storing the data into some type of array.